Flutter just_audio proxyHandler 'useProxyForRequestHeaders: true' causing high CPU usage for iOS devices
I need proxyHandlers for some reasons (implemented some functionality with passes through these handlers). But I have no idea, how these part of code causing so much use of CPU for iOS devices. As my iOS native knowledges are so limited, I am spending a lot of time with the issue. Any practical solution for improving these proxyHandlers.

add some code here

Why? It is not a question which the problem is in few lines of code. If someone wants actually help, he/she must use the plugin and they can just search the parameter I wrote about.

huge amount of programmers are using this package. there are meny issues on github repo. but looks like only you faced this issue. it is ok, but there is possibility, that your code is important to some clarification of this issue.

Nope, it is not only me, some are just making the value of useProxyForRequestHeaders false. But I edited the plugin's proxyHandler method a bit to add refresh token feature. So it means I can't just do useProxyForRequestHeaders = false. There are 3-4 Github issues related to this problem, but all of them are closed without clear answer or fix.
